# Insert a record into SQL Server via email

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, email

I am developing a ticket system via asp.net and using SQL Server. I want to insert a record into SQL Server via email.

For example: new insert record to ticket table when user sends an email to `support@....com`.

How can I do this? Is this attribute of SQL Server or mail server?

Comment: This is a very broad question; please narrow it down a bit, show what research you've done and what you have tried so far. [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What is the best way for this job? I need to your ideas.